# Solve system of equations with implicit function

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, system, implicit

I am trying to solve a system of 3 (non-linear) equations with two variables $x,\ y$ and one unknown function $f(x,y)$ of these two variables. Also, the system includes the change of this function $f$ upon the change of variables, i.e. something like:

$(1)\ \ \ \frac{1}{a+\frac{x}{f(x,y)}}(\frac{1}{f(x,y)} - \frac{x}{(f(x,y)^2}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}) + \frac{1}{-f(x,y)^2-\frac{x}{f(x,y)}}((\frac{x}{f(x,y)^2}-f(x,y))\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} - \frac{1}{f(x,y)}) = 0$

$(2)\ \ \ \frac{1}{a+\frac{y}{f(x,y)}}(\frac{1}{f(x,y)} - \frac{y}{(f(x,y)^2}\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}) + \frac{1}{-f(x,y)^2-\frac{y}{f(x,y)}}((\frac{y}{f(x,y)^2}-f(x,y))\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} - \frac{1}{f(x,y)}) = 0$

$(3)\ \ \ \frac{1}{b^2f(x,y)^2-\frac{x}{bf(x,y)}}(b^2f(x,y)+\frac{xb}{(bf(x,y))^2}) + \frac{1}{c^2f(x,y)^2-\frac{y}{cf(x,y)}}(c^2f(x,y)+\frac{yc}{(cf(x,y))^2}) = 0$

I want to find $x,\ y,\ f(x,y)$. I have tried working with Solve but I had problems with passing the $f$ function both as an argument and object of interest. For example (a slightly simplified example):

`Solve[{D[f[x, y], x] + a x + b y + f[x, y] == 1, 
  x - y - D[f[x, y], y] == 2, f[x, y] - x^2 - y^2 = 0}, {x, y}]`

does not work. I have also tried with DSolve.

Could someone help me how to deal with this in mathematica?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For a start you would need to input the system in Mathematica syntax.

Comment: The solution to your third equation is either $f(x,y) = 0$ (in which case the other two equations are satisfied and $x$ and $y$ are arbitrary) or $Gx + Hy = 0$, which allows you to eliminate either $x$ or $y$ from the other two equations.  This should simplify your life somewhat.

Comment: I tried to ask this question in a more general way, but was for obvious reasons unsuccessful :). Thus, I edited with a close to actual system. Thanks for replies anyway!

Comment: The third equation has a = instead of the necessary ==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Question contains two different sets of equations.  I chose to solve the one in Mathematica format.  Begin with the third equation, which (after correcting a syntax error) is solved by

```
First@Solve[f[x, y] - x^2 - y^2 == 0, f[x, y]]
(* {f[x, y] -> x^2 + y^2} *)
```

Substitute this solution into the first and second equations, holding them `Unevaluated` so that the substitution occurs before the differentiation.

```
Unevaluated[{D[f[x, y], x] + a x + b y + f[x, y] == 1, 
   x - y - D[f[x, y], y] == 2}] /. %
(* {2 x + a x + x^2 + b y + y^2 == 1, x - 3 y == 2} *)

Solve[%, {x, y}]
(* {{x -> 1/20 (-14 - 9 a - 3 b - 3 Sqrt[44 + 28 a + 9 a^2 + 36 b + 6 a b + b^2]), 
     y -> 1/20 (-18 - 3 a - b - Sqrt[44 + 28 a + 9 a^2 + 36 b + 6 a b + b^2])}, 
    {x -> 1/20 (-14 - 9 a - 3 b + 3 Sqrt[44 + 28 a + 9 a^2 + 36 b + 6 a b + b^2]), 
     y -> 1/20 (-18 - 3 a - b + Sqrt[44 + 28 a + 9 a^2 + 36 b + 6 a b + b^2])}} *)
```

The more complex equation (not in Mathematica format) would be solved in the same way.  First, `Solve` the third equation for `f`.  Then, substitute the result into the first and second equations and `Solve` for `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I am getting complex numbers. Should I maybe rather try to solve this system numerically? If so, could you recommend some particular method for this?

Comment: Solving the equations numerically will produce the same results.  Almost certainly, solving the third equation yielded multiple roots for `f`.  Have you tried them all?  If so and you are confident that all the answers you obtain are incorrect, I suggest that you pose a new question that includes the code you used and an explanation of why you believe that the answer is incorrect.